# Color svg paths based on position along gradient in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm working with a bunch of svg paths, and I'd like to color them based on their positions along a gradient. The image below is a sketch of my situation. Not the actual chart.

[image]

I've been digging around and it seems a mask might be a solution, but I can't seem to get it working.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
var overlaySvg = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'overlay-svg');

var defs = svg.append('defs');

var gradient = defs.append("linearGradient")
    .attr("id", "gradient")
    .attr('gradientUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .attr("x1", "0")
    .attr("y1", "0")
    .attr("x2", "100%")
    .attr("y2", "0%");

gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "10%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#0081c5");

gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "50%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#aaa");

gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "80%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#ed1c24");

var rect = mask.append('rect')
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)

svg.selectAll('g.chart-container path')
  .attr('d', line)
  .classed('line', true)
  .attr('stroke', 'url(#gradient)')
  .attr("mask", "url(#gradient-mask)");
```

What am I doing wrong? Are there other alternatives? Would a filter be suitable for this situation? Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE**:
Here is what my actual chart looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a mask, just use a gradient fill where the gradient has been defined with gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse". That way the gradient is defined in user space and with the appropriate stops you'll get the right color to fill your shapes at each x value.

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px">
  <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="10" y1="0" x2="600" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255)" />
       <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:1" />         
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  

  <path d="M 0 0 q 200 200 0 400" stroke="url(#grad1)" fill="none" stroke-width="5px"/>
    <path d="M 100 0 q 200 200 0 400" stroke="url(#grad1)" fill="none" stroke-width="5px"/>
    <path d="M 200 0 q 200 200 0 400" stroke="url(#grad1)" fill="none" stroke-width="5px"/>
    <path d="M 300 0 q 200 200 0 400" stroke="url(#grad1)" fill="none" stroke-width="5px"/>
      <path d="M 400 0 q 200 200 0 400" stroke="url(#grad1)" fill="none" stroke-width="5px"/>
      <path d="M 500 0 q 200 200 0 400" stroke="url(#grad1)" fill="none" stroke-width="5px"/>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, Michael, for your response. It seems like I'm getting closer to my goal. I updated my question with an image to what my chart looks like now. Ideally, what I'd like to do is have the lines colored based on the gradient, but have the rectangle behind it be hidden. That's why I inquired about a mask.

Comment: You don't need a mask - updated the answer with an SVG snippet. In your code, you're specifying userSpaceOnUse but then actually putting percentages, which are being interpreted as zeros and 1's in pixels. In SVG, you can fix things relative to the main drawing canvas - which is really different than how CSS works.